# What do you call a bathroom with no toilet?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, dialects

Might seem like a trick question at first, but I'm serious.

When the toilet is in one room by itself (let's call this the "restroom"), and the place with the sink, washing machine, shower room and bathtub, is another room... what do you call that other room?

This is a common layout in Japanese houses and apartments, but it's not easily described in English. Because in the West the toilet and bath are together and described as a "bathroom", leading to the term "bathroom" being used loosely to label any toilet room. Which would be fine, except in the case where their *actually is a room for taking a bath and washing up, but it has no toilet*. So what do you call it?

Oh, and I almost forgot to mention that "shower room" describes the specific enclosed space where one takes a shower, so we can't call this larger wash space a shower room. Furthermore, "washroom" is synonymous with "bathroom", so we're back to not having a name to describe a room for only bathing and washing hands (and sometimes laundry).

Comment: Which version of English are you talking about? Because BrE doesn't use "bathroom" to refer to a room containing a toilet, but a room containing a bath/shower, Britain has two words available for the two distinct rooms.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I live in Britain, and if somebody mentioned a bathroom, I'd automatically assume that it'd have a toilet.  Just saying.

Comment: @AndrewLeach Thank you for pointing that out. I mean primarily within the context of American English. But it's nice to know that at least in Britain it hasn't been mixed up (as much - thank you @Lordology). I'm not sure if it's due to architectural trends or what, but in the U.S. if you ask where the bathroom is you will almost certainly be led to the toilet. Although to be fair, the definition including a toilet is listed second in my dictionary.

Comment: France has a lot of bathrooms (bath/shower and/or bidet) **without a toilet**, which is often in a separate cabinet de toilette.

Comment: I have never heard of a laundry room with a bathtub or a shower. I expect that they’re extremely rare in the English speaking world.

Comment: @Laurel It's more like for lack of a dedicated laundry room (due to limited space), the washing machine's place ends up being in the same room where you do other washing activities. Dryers are much less common, as Japanese people generally hang their clothes to dry on a balcony.

Comment: In Australia it's common for the "bathroom" to have a shower, bath, and sink but no toilet, with the toilet in a small adjacent room that in some cases may also have a small sink. But some houses and a lot of apartments have their toilet in the bathroom. The washing machine would normally be in a different room (the "laundry") except perhaps in some smaller apartments. If you are in someone else's home and ask to use the bathroom that would normally mean the toilet regardless of layout.

Comment: Lynneguist discussed the difference between British and American terminology in this are [at some length](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2007/03/toilet.html) in 2007.

Comment: I was watching Paper Moon again on a long haul flight, and if you Americans went back, like the little girl, to using “shithouse”, there’d be no problem understanding that a bathroom was for bathing.

Comment: Once, in a sociology text, I read in a section about public 'housing projects' in the USA, a quote from a tenant of the infamous Pruitt-Igoe project in St Louis, Missouri. She said she was tired of people getting into her apartment building and "going to the bathroom" in the stairwell. My first thought was "how enlightened of the city authorities to provide bathrooms so widely".

Comment: I don't think there's a word specifically for this. "washroom" is another room for "bathroom", and it seems like it might be more appropriate for the part that only contains the sink.

Comment: *"I almost forgot to mention that "shower room" describes the specific enclosed space where one takes a shower"* - Not in Australia. We would either say "shower stall" or just "shower", with the stall usually being within a larger room with space to stand while getting dressed and usually at least a sink and mirror if not also a bath and/or toilet.

Answer (score 3):

Shower room.  It was a thing in the fifties.  Our house has one.  Shower and sink.  That’s it.  A shower only in a room is called a shower stall.

Comment: Thank you! If you can cite a source, I will most likely accept this as the answer.